# Connecting to Microsoft SQL Server with Autohotkey?

Tags: sql-server, autohotkey

I have an ahk script that I run each day but first, I have to hard code the data into it after I run a query. Is it possible to connect to SQL Server via Autohotkey? This would obviously be ideal. I've read a few articles but haven't had success doing it thus far.

I tried the sample logic below with no luck.

Thanks!

```
ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pw;Initial Catalog=db;Data Source=server;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False"
Query := "select * from tbl"
Table := ADOSQL(ConnectionString, Query)
Loop % Table.MaxIndex() - 1 ; We subtract 1 in order to skip one row (which will be the column titles, as we are adding 1 to the counter below).
{
     CURRENT_ROW := A_Index + 1 ; We add one to our current row counter in order to start on row 2 (skip row 1).
     Loop % Table[CURRENT_ROW].MaxIndex()
     {
          CURRENT_COLUMN := A_Index
          msgbox % Table[CURRENT_ROW, CURRENT_COLUMN]
     }
}
```

Comment: Your title got me imagining hijinks like `:*:FROM::DROP TABLE`